# What is the one word for "_exact opposite of horrible_"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, vocabulary

**"The older team is being treated horribly by the management"**

To this I want to say 'So is the new team' in this way - **"The new team is not being treated** *'the exact opposite of horrible* **'ly either."**.

How do I say that?  What word should I use to replace the *italic* part?

Thank you.

Comment: Without further details to understand what "horrible" means in context, any antonym of "horrible" might work.

Comment: @user3169: not talked to with proper respect, threatening to fire, not serving good food or other requirements otherwise promised. hope this clears the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

They are not exactly opposite, but **well** or **nicely** would be the natural words to use in that situation. If you were prepared to lower the bar a bit on the positive side, **properly** would work as well.